# Image spot detection in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I have millions of images containing every day photos. I'm trying to find a way to pick out those in which some certain colours are present, say, red and orange, disregarding the shape or object. The size may matter - e.g., at least 50x50 px.

Is there an efficient and lightweight library for achieving this? I know there is OpenCV and it seems quite powerful, but would it be too bloated for this task? It's a relatively simple task, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Certainly OpenCV can do this, but you could also use the Python Imaging Library [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and just create a function to iterate through the image cropping small blocks of the image set at your minimum size, and testing these blocks average colour and tolerance against the matching criteria. Something along the lines of (untested pseudo code):

```
import Image

im = Image.open("test_picture.png")
for y in xrange(image_height - block_height):
    for x in xrange(image_width - block_width):
        block = im.crop(x, y, x + block_width, y + block_height)
        if colour_test(block):   # test for match
            return True
```

Its very easy to get the colour frequency info of an image using `block.getcolors()`, so you can easily write the `colour_test()` function.

Comment: As an alternative to OpenCV and PIL, there is the [Mahotas package](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas). I am a practitioner in computer vision and I personally dislike PIL, scikits.image, and OpenCV very much, though each has certain things that it accels at. Mahotas is based purely on scipy.ndimage data type, which is convenient in many situations. The only issue I found was sometimes needing an additional library, [PyPNG](http://code.google.com/p/pypng/), when dealing with PNG images.

Comment: @EMS: why do you need PyPNG? Are there PNGs not correctly opened by mahotas? I just changed the way mahotas deals with PNGs (since the version released yesterday, it uses the imread package). Email me with examples if there are images that don't work well. Tx

Comment: I think it was an old version of Mahotas; I just re-installed and it appears to do fine without PyPNG.

Comment: @EMS maybe too much for a comment but can you elaborate on the key things that make you dislike so much PIL, scikits.image and OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a library but you could segment these areas using a simple thresholding segmentation algorithm. Say, you want to find red spots. Extract the red channel from the image, select a threshold, and eliminate pixels that are below the threshold. The resulting pixels are your spots. To find a suitable threshold you can build the image's red channel histogram and find the valley there. The lowest point in the valley is the threshold that you could use. If there are more than one valley, smooth the histogram until there is one valley and two peaks. You can use a Gaussian function to smooth the histogram. To find the spots from the remaining pixels you can use the labeling algorithm and then find the connected components in the graph that the labeling algorithm produced. Yes, it is simple. :)